# Splatting with Move-Item gives an error

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Ok, so the script itself is over 500 lines long, so I'll refrain from posting the entire thing. However, I have narrowed down the issue to a single line.

If I use the below line of code, everything works as expected.

```
Move-Item -Path $path -Include *.txt,*.doc,*.pdf -Destination $dest -Force
```

But when I change it to use splatting, it gives me an error

```
$downloadDir = "G:\Downloads"
$dest = "G:\Test\"
$editList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$downloadDir" -include "[" -File | ForEach-Object -Process {Rename-item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace "[][]"," ") -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
$mainList = Get-ChildItem -Path "$downloadDir" -File | Select-Object Name

ForEach ($list in $mainList) {
    $item = $list.Name
    $path = "$downloadDir\*"
    $opts = @{
        Path = $path;
        Include = '*.txt,*.doc,*.pdf';
        Force = $true;
        Destination = $dest
    }
    Move-Item @opts
}

Move-Item : Cannot move item because the item at 'G:\Downloads\test.txt' does not exist.
```

I feel like I am probably missing something very basic, but I don't know enough about hash tables/splatting yet, to spot the mistake.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Just to clarify, G:\Downloads\test.txt comes from $path which is generated from a Get-ChildItem.

I am literally doing a straight swap of the 2 versions of code(Splatting/Non-splatting).

EDIT 2:
Added all the parts of the script relevant to that Move-Item

EDIT 3:
Got this working by using double quotes for the "Include" line:

```
Include = "*.txt","*.doc","*.pdf";
```

Comment: Which argument is `G:\Downloads\test.txt`? And this fails if you replace the single line with the splatted option in the script directly?

Comment: Sorry, should have explained that. Basically "G:\Downloads\test.txt" comes from $path, which is generated prior to this part of the script. Essentially comes from a Get-ChildItem being ran on G:\Downloads.

Yes. This error appears with the swap.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but the `-Include` argument takes an array of strings, not a string that contains comma separated items.  Try `Include = '*.txt','*.doc','*.pdf';`

Comment: 'G:\Downloads\test.txt' is a string, and `Get-ChildItem` produces a `[FileInfo]` object. Are you assigning `$Path` to the FullName property, or could this be a matter of PowerShell expanding the FileInfo object incorrectly when splatting? Are you able to exclude the `Path` argument and pipe `$Path` to the Move-Item cmdlet and have it work correctly?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician might be on to something here. Could you include the code that actually assigns a value to `$path`? Also might help to try assigning a literal string to `Path` in the hashtable, like `@{ Path = 'G:\Downloads\test.txt' }` just to see if that works. Both of these could help determine whether this is the source of the problem.

Comment: Updated the OP to contain all the relevant parts of the script, pertaining to the Move-Item - I'll try the literal path, in about an hour.

Comment: Ok, so literally adding a path to the "Path" and "Destination" still doesn't work. However, commenting out the "Include" does. I have tried using: `Include = '*.txt','*.doc','*.pdf';` which was also unsuccessful

Comment: Thanks @BaconBits, while the single quotes did not work, it lead me to try using the double quotes, which did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Include from:

```
  Include = '*.txt,*.doc,*.pdf';
```

to

```
  Include = "*.txt","*.doc","*.pdf";
```

The Path statement can be tricky as well.

For example

```
get-childitem c:\temp -include *.txt
```

will not work, while

```
get-childitem c:\temp\* -include *.txt
```

will work, if you have any .txt files in c:\temp

It's stupid, but that's how it is with some of these cmdlets.

Comment: While the single quotes did not work, it lead me to try using the double quotes, which did work, so thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Huh! I thought it worked for me on v5 when I tested it. So, * was the problem?

Comment: I was already using \* but when I changed the "Include" to be `Include = "*.txt","*.doc","*.pdf";`, it started working. Also, I'm currently using v4, so maybe there's a slight difference in the way it was being processed?

Comment: Cool, thanks for update. I will change the answer to use "" instead to be safe